# $this->getsummarycount() not working custom block

Tags: cart, module, shopping-cart

$this->getsummarycount() not working custom block. i want add cart widget template custom block. but `$_cartQty = $this->getSummaryCount();` can't get value can you tell me any helper file or any block call for it.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery(".top-mini-title").hover(function(){
jQuery(".top-mini-content").addClass('icon-up').removeClass('icon-down').slideDown(200);
});
jQuery(".main-div-top").mouseleave(function(){
jQuery(".top-mini-content").addClass('icon-down').removeClass('icon-up').slideUp(100);
});
});

</script>

<div class="block block-cart main-div-top icon-down">
    <?php $_cartQty = $this->getSummaryCount(); ?>

    <div class="block-title top-mini-title">
        <strong><span><?php echo $this->__('My Cart') ?></span></strong>
    </div>
    <div class="block-content top-mini-content" style="display:none;">
    <?php if ($_cartQty>0): ?>
        <div class="summary">
            <?php if ($_cartQty==1): ?>
                <p class="amount"><?php echo $this->__('There is <a href="%s">1 item</a> in your cart.', $this->getUrl('checkout/cart')) ?></p>
            <?php else: ?>
                <p class="amount"><?php echo $this->__('There are <a href="%s">%s items</a> in your cart.', $this->getUrl('checkout/cart'), $_cartQty) ?></p>
            <?php endif ?>
            <p class="subtotal">
                <?php if ($this->canApplyMsrp()): ?>
                    <span class="map-cart-sidebar-total"><?php echo $this->__('ORDER TOTAL WILL BE DISPLAYED BEFORE YOU SUBMIT THE ORDER'); ?></span>
                <?php else: ?>
                    <span class="label"><?php echo $this->__('Cart Subtotal:') ?></span> <?php echo Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($this->getSubtotal()) ?>
                    <?php if ($_subtotalInclTax = $this->getSubtotalInclTax()): ?>
                        <br />(<?php echo Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_subtotalInclTax) ?> <?php echo Mage::helper('tax')->getIncExcText(true) ?>)
                    <?php endif; ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </p>
        </div>
    <?php endif ?>
    <?php if($_cartQty && $this->isPossibleOnepageCheckout()): ?>
    <div class="actions">
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('extra_actions') ?>
        <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Checkout') ?>" class="button" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getCheckoutUrl() ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Checkout') ?></span></span></button>
    </div>
    <?php endif ?>
    <?php $_items = $this->getRecentItems() ?>
    <?php if(count($_items)): ?>
        <p class="block-subtitle"><?php echo $this->__('Recently added item(s)') ?></p>
        <ol id="cart-sidebar" class="mini-products-list">
        <?php foreach($_items as $_item): ?>
            <?php echo $this->getItemHtml($_item) ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ol>
        <script type="text/javascript">decorateList('cart-sidebar', 'none-recursive')</script>
    <?php else: ?>
        <p class="empty"><?php echo $this->__('You have no items in your shopping cart.') ?></p>
    <?php endif ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you put full code

Comment: I am adding code in myquestion.

Answer (score 1):

Your custom block must be extended from **Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart_Sidebar** because this block's class has this method:

```
/**
 * Get shopping cart items qty based on configuration (summary qty or items qty)
 *
 * @return int | float
 */
public function getSummaryCount()
{
    if ($this->getData('summary_qty')) {
        return $this->getData('summary_qty');
    }
    return Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getSummaryQty();
}
```

Also instead, you can get this information through helper, as in **Mage_Checkout_Block_Links**:

```
    $count = $this->getSummaryQty() ? $this->getSummaryQty()
        : $this->helper('checkout/cart')->getSummaryCount();
    if ($count == 1) {
        $text = $this->__('My Cart (%s item)', $count);
    } elseif ($count > 0) {
        $text = $this->__('My Cart (%s items)', $count);
    } else {
        $text = $this->__('My Cart');
    }
```

, i.e. you should use $this->helper('checkout/cart')->getSummaryCount();